# Image is being displayed on the same HTML page using jsPDF instead of opening a PDF view when run on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, jspdf

I have written a simple code which takes input from the user (basically an html form) and then creates a PDF certificate based on the user input. I am using jsPDF library to generate the PDF. The code works absolutely fine when run on Firefox. Once the user submits the form, the certificate is opened in the PDF view. However, if I run the same code (html file) on chrome, PDF view is not opened and instead, the certificate image is generated on the same page. Please refer my code below.

```
<html>
<body>
<form id="frm1">
Application  <input type="text" name="app"><br>
Initiative  <input type="text" name="iniative"><br><br>
Description-Problem / Scope  <input type="text" name="initi"><br><br>
Describe solution proposed  <input type="text" name="dsolution"><br><br>
Approx effort saved per month <input type="text" name="approx"><br><br>
Ticket reduction in % <input type="text" name="tic"><br><br>
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:load123()" value="Submit">


</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-ui-   1.8.17.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/dist/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<script>

function load123()
{
   if( frm1.initi.value.length == "" )
     {

        alert( "Please provide your Application name " );
        document.myForm.Name.focus() ;
        return false;

     } 

var getImageFromUrl = function(url, callback) {
    var img = new Image(), data, ret = {
        data: null,
        pending: true
    };

    img.onError = function() {
        throw new Error('Cannot load image: "'+url+'"');
    };
    img.onload = function() {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;

        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        // Grab the image as a jpeg encoded in base64, but only the data
        data = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg').slice('data:image/jpeg;base64,'.length);
        // Convert the data to binary form
        data = atob(data);
        document.body.removeChild(canvas);

        ret['data'] = data;
        ret['pending'] = false;
        if (typeof callback === 'function') {
            callback(data);
        }
    };
    img.src = url;

    return ret;
};

var createPDF = function(imgData) {
var doc = new jsPDF('landscape');


doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 18, 20, 270, 165);
doc.setFontSize(40);
doc.setTextColor(0,0,255);
doc.setFont("helvetica");
doc.setFontType("bold");
doc.text(48, 50, 'Continous Improvement Initiative');

doc.setFontSize(25);
doc.setTextColor(255,0,0);
doc.setFont("times");
doc.setFontType("bold");   
doc.text(48, 70, 'Application: ');

doc.setFontSize(25);
doc.setTextColor(0,0,0);
doc.setFont("times");
doc.setFontType("bold");   
doc.text(96, 70, frm1.app.value);

doc.setFontSize(25);
doc.setTextColor(255,0,0);
doc.setFont("times");
doc.setFontType("bold");   
doc.text(48, 85, 'Description - Problem / Scope Statement: ');

doc.setFontSize(25);
doc.setTextColor(0,0,0);
doc.setFont("times");
doc.setFontType("bold");   
doc.text(48, 90, frm1.initi.value);

doc.setFontSize(25);
doc.setTextColor(255,0,0);
doc.setFont("times");
doc.setFontType("bold");   
doc.text(48, 105, 'Description - Solution Proposed: ');

doc.setFontSize(25);
doc.setTextColor(0,0,0);
doc.setFont("times");
doc.setFontType("bold");   
doc.text(173, 105, frm1.dsolution.value);

doc.setFontSize(25);
doc.setTextColor(255,0,0);
doc.setFont("times");
doc.setFontType("bold");   
doc.text(48, 120, 'Approx. efforts saved / Month: ');

doc.setFontSize(25);
doc.setTextColor(0,0,0);
doc.setFont("times");
doc.setFontType("bold");   
doc.text(165, 120, frm1.approx.value);

doc.setFontSize(25);
doc.setTextColor(255,0,0);
doc.setFont("times");
doc.setFontType("bold");   
doc.text(48, 135, 'Ticket Resolution in %: ');

doc.setFontSize(25);
doc.setTextColor(0,0,0);
doc.setFont("times");
doc.setFontType("bold");   
doc.text(140, 135, frm1.tic.value);


doc.output('datauri');
}

getImageFromUrl('template.png', createPDF);

} 

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

To test it use any image with name 'template.png'.

**PS:** It works on Chrome if it is triggered using Brackets editor. But, not when you run the file directly on Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the data url for the image (template.png) solved the problem.

Generate the data url [here](http://dataurl.net/#dataurlmaker)